# Print 2 strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing

I have 2 arrays:

```
String [] head = {"Name", "Date of birth", "PPS number"};
String [] personal= {value1, value2, value3};
```

I want this 2 arrays to be printed out in the following manner:

```
head[0] tab personal[0]
head[1] tab personal[1]
head[2] tab personal [2]
```

I tried different options and can't get this working properly.
Any suggestions?
Many thanks in advance!

Rafal

Comment: Please show your 'different options'... if this is homework please add the 'homework' tag.

Comment: Use a loop and print them; otherwise, if the number of elements in your array is a relatively low constant, just print it manually.

Comment: We really need to see some sort of effort- this question is too easy not to at least get a hacked at attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide any evidence of your attempts, I'll assume you didn't try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < head.length; i++)
  System.out.println(head[i]+"\t"+personal[i]);
```

At least I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sincerely, everyone is able to find the solution, but the OP is obviously learning. You just did his homework.

Comment: @JBNizet Technically, we don't know its homework. And if I did, at least he has an answer now. I just assume that he wants an answer and hasn't had one. I'm not looking for rep. I don't see any reason for -1 on a working answer.

Comment: Because it's not useful for the OP. Cutting 'n pasting is not how you learn. You haven't even explained what your code did, and why this was the solution.

Comment: @JBNizet I think your downvote was a bad decision. [From the FAQ from Homework answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/186544): 
`Don't downvote others who answer homework questions in good faith, even if they break these guidelines. It's not always obvious at first glance that a question is homework, especially when you're not expecting to see it here. It is a good idea to suggest editing the response in a comment.`

Comment: +1 because I agree it's not fair to downvote this. No hw tag, clean, correct code, answers the question. I did downvote the **question** itself and voted to close as it clearly shows no research effort.

Comment: I'll remove my downvote if Jon elaborates a bit more. When this answer was posted, there were already 5 upvotes on the comment asking the OP to show what he tried.